# How can I assign something to nothing in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

For example, I have something like this:

```
reg b5,b3,b2,b0;
wire [5:0] vector;

assign {b5,<unused>,b3,b2,<unused>,b0} = vector;
```

I don't care about bits 1 and 4 of vector.

What is the best thing to use instead of ? 1'bZ? 1'b0? or 1'bX? Or...?

Comment: Could you create dummy wires to use as "spacers" and then ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
reg b5,b3,b2,b0;
wire [5:0] vector;
reg dummy1, dummy2;

assign {b5,dummy1,b3,b2,dummy2,b0} = vector;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign only the bits that you actually do care about.

```
assign b5 = vector[5];
assign b3 = vector[3];
assign b2 = vector[2];
assign b0 = vector[0];
```

You can also do this with subsets of the vector:

```
reg [1:0] 2bits;
wire [5:0] vector;
assign 2bits = vector[1:0];
```